Geting 503 error from my wordpress site after clicking a button
My WordPress site working properly, until I clicked a button name "Update". Whenever I click the button it shows
503
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily busy, try again later!

I have tried deactivating plugins and themes, but the issue is still here.
And I cannot find the error log in public_html file.
Here is the code spinet:
    <div class="head"><b>Editing products:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="showVersion" onclick="showCloseVersion()"><?=(isset($_COOKIE['textVersion'])?$_COOKIE['textVersion']:'Show');?></span></div>
<?php
// Покажем форму ввода
 if(empty($_COOKIE['showVersion'])) $_COOKIE['showVersion']=0;
 echo '<div class="spoilerVersion edit_fields" style="display:'.($_COOKIE['showVersion']==1?'block':'none').'">';
 echo '<form class="edit_form" method="get">';
  foreach($ar_prog as $str) {
   if(iconv_strlen($str)>1) {
    echo '<div class="formdwl">';
    echo 'Program: <input type="text" class="edit_prog" name="edit_prog[]" value="'.explode("~", $str)[0].'" />';
    echo ' Version: <input type="text" class="edit_vers" name="edit_prog[]" value="'.explode("~", $str)[1].'" />';
    echo ' Trial version days: <input type="text" class="edit_time" name="edit_prog[]" value="'.explode("~", $str)[2].'" />';
    echo ' Package type auto-registration: <select class="reg_form" name="edit_prog[]">
                                            <option value="">-----</option>';
                                            foreach ($packages as $i) {
                                             echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.(explode("~", $str)[3]==$i?'selected':'').'>'.$i.'</option>';
                                            }
                                            echo '</select>';
    //echo ' Number of activations: <input type="text" class="edit_time" name="edit_prog[]" value="'.explode(",", $str)[4].'" />';
    echo ' <input type="hidden" class="edit_time" name="edit_prog[]" value="'.explode("~", $str)[4].'" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="edit_prog[]" value="|" />';
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/';
  if($open = scandir($path)) {
    $list=array();
    foreach($open as $v) {
      if(strstr($v, explode(".", explode("~", $str)[0])[0])) {
        $list[] = $v;
      }
    }
    natcasesort($list);
    foreach($list as $v) {
       if(strstr($v, explode(".", explode("~", $str)[0])[0])) {
        switch(explode(".", $v)[1]) {
          case 'ex4':$color='006f03'; break;
          case 'ex5':$color='002ca9'; break;
          case 'jpg':$color='00b6ec'; break;
          case 'JPG':$color='c70081'; break;
          case 'png':$color='00b381'; break;
          case 'PNG':$color='8b9407'; break;
          case 'gif':$color='e07200'; break;
          default: $color='000';
        }
        if(explode(".", $v)[1]=='ex4' || explode(".", $v)[1]=='ex5') echo ', <a style="color:#'.$color.';text-decoration:none" href="'.($administrator?'storage?nm='.$v:'').'" onclick="return confirm(\'Delete file?\')">'.$v.' ('.date('d.m.Y',filectime($path.$v)).')</a>';
        else echo ', <a style="color:#'.$color.';text-decoration:none" href="'.($administrator?'storage?nm='.$v:'').'" onclick="return confirm(\'Delete file?\')">'.$v.'</a>';
      }
    }
  }
    echo '</div>';
   }
  }

